# Is there a way i can achieve this kind of slider in flutter if yes then how can i?

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-animation

[This is the slider i want to create in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRCDv.gif)

I did try the carasoul slider but can't able to achieve this kind of slider and also i tried with animated positioned but some how the slider animation was not possible for me in that approach maybe because i don't have proper knowledge of animation in flutter. if anyone kind enough to help me with this it would be very helpful. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is this kind of card slider.
I think that is possible to ajust the adjecent images to show less image (to overlap the next image or the previous).
And also to make it autoplay.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKByaGFcxnE

Comment: thanks for referring but I already watched this one and it doesn't match the requirement